# How to get AWS Cognito user email attributes in android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am new to Android and Amazon Web Services.
I am trying to fetch AWS Cognito user attributes from my android app.
I found that I can use the method ***getDetailsHandler*** to get the list of user attributes.
But how can I map my IdentityProvider(this is what I have after the user is logged in) to this ***getDetailsHandler***?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handler is more of a callback, it gives you a chance to handle errors or utilize the response. The [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-android-sdk.html) has a sample on how to do this, but the gist is you need to call it with the user that has signed in:

```
user.getDetails(getDetailsHandler);
```

And you can get the user like this:

```
CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(context, userPoolId, clientId, clientSecret);
...
CognitoUser user = userPool.getCurrentUser();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want use Amplify SDK you can get verified information like;

Email

```
Amplify.Auth.fetchUserAttributes().find { it.key.keyString == "email_verified" }?.value.toBoolean()
```

Phone

```
Amplify.Auth.fetchUserAttributes().find { it.key.keyString == "phone_number_verified" }?.value.toBoolean()
```

Answer (score 0):

In **2023**

If you are using Amplify SDK then you can get other information like this :

```
Amplify.Auth.fetchUserAttributes(
                { result ->
                    Toast.makeText(this, "User Attributes: ${result.find { it.key.keyString == "email" }?.value}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                },
                { error ->
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error: $error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            )
```